# Access Key Value pair in XML directly

Tags: xml, powershell

Given this sample XML data, is it possible to access a Key directly?

eg: $xml.root.User_Blob.LogonMethod

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<root>
  <User_Blob>
    <Item>
      <Key>LogonMethod</Key>
      <Value>prompt</Value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Key>ServerURLEntered</Key>
      <Value>http://myserver/config.xml</Value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Key>ServerURLListUsers</Key>
      <Value>
        <LSOption>http://myurl/config.xml</LSOption>
        <LSOption>http://myurl</LSOption>
      </Value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Key>UserDisplayDimensions</Key>
      <Value>fullscreen</Value>
    </Item>
  </User_Blob>
```

Comment: Is the closing tag intentionally missing?

Comment: @stej: sorry that was an error, I didn't want to post more xml than needed but forgot the closing tag. (corrected it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:-

```
[xml]$xmlObject = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("Filepath")   

Write-Host $xmlObject.root.User_Blob.Item.Key
```

**OR**

```
$xmlObject = New-Object XML
$xmlObject.Load("YourFilePath")
$xmlObject.root.User_Blob.Item.Key
```

To get the value for **LogonMethod**, try this way:-

```
($xmlObject.root.User_Blob.Item | Where-Object { $_.Key -eq 'LogonMethod' }).Value
```

**OR**

Still otherway:-

```
$xmlObject.selectSingleNode("/root/User_Blob/Item[Key = 'LogonMethod']/Value").get_innerXml()
```

Comment: $xml.root.User_Blob.Item.Key["LogonMethod"] fails with Cannot index into a null array. Probably due to Item appearing more than once.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: I had hoped there was a way to use without using For-Each/Where but I think it's indeed the only way. This works for me:
   ($xml.root.User_Blob.Item | Where-Object { $_.Key -eq 'LogonMethod' }).Value
(so not Item.Value but just Item), if you update your answer I will accept it.

Comment: I am not getting any output, it just everything I wrote in PS and at the end adds prompt.

Answer (score 6):

Personally I cases when `Where-Object` is needed, I would use `Select-Xml`:

```
$c = [xml]'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<root>
  <User_Blob>
    <Item>
      <Key>LogonMethod</Key>
      <Value>prompt</Value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Key>ServerURLEntered</Key>
      <Value>http://myserver/config.xml</Value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Key>ServerURLListUsers</Key>
      <Value>
        <LSOption>http://myurl/config.xml</LSOption>
        <LSOption>http://myurl</LSOption>
      </Value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Key>UserDisplayDimensions</Key>
      <Value>fullscreen</Value>
    </Item>
  </User_Blob></root>'
($c | Select-Xml -XPath "//Item[Key = 'LogonMethod']").Node.Value
```

It's much cleaner (if you know what you are doing).

Comment: +1 But this is more clear for me: ( $c | Select-Xml -XPath "//Item[Key = 'LogonMethod']" ).node.value

Comment: +1 but a question, how can we update a value when using Select-XML ?

Comment: @Christian, do you use V2 or V3 CTP? `($c | Select-Xml -XPath "//Item[Key = 'LogonMethod']/Value").Node.Value` returns nothing

Comment: @stej V2. And [xml]$c = gc file.xml. Delete the /value in your path!!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use SelectSingleNode method:

```
$xml.SelectSingleNode("//*[Key='LogonMethod']").Value
```