# Importing XML into Powershell as structured data

Tags: xml, powershell

Looking at the documentation,  there are commands for importing and exporting  `Json` and `csv` data in Powershell. For `Xml` there only seems to be `ConvertTo-Xml`.
I anticipate working with `Xml` allot more and it is thus far prooving difficult getting `Xml` data into powershell sessions.

I tried a number of solutions all using what looks to be `.Net` or `C#` calls to import `Xml` and thus far all have given me errors, I dont know any `.Net` or `C#`.
For example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9259258/17841256) answer suggests to do:

```xml
[xml]$xmlObject = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("Filepath")   

Write-Host $xmlObject.root.User_Blob.Item.Key
```

I tied the solution using the question askers own `Xml`:

```
[xml]$xmlObject = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("C:temp\Sample 2.xml")
Write-Host $xmlObject.root.User_Blob.Item.Key
```

I got this error:

```
MetadataError: Cannot convert value "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>  
<root>  
<User_Blob>  
<Item>  
<Key>LogonMethod</Key>  
<Value>prompt</Value>  
</Item>  
<Item>  
<Key>ServerURLEntered</Key>  
<Value>http://myserver/config.xml</Value>  
</Item>  
<Item>  
<Key>ServerURLListUsers</Key>  
<Value>  
<LSOption>http://myurl/config.xml</LSOption>  
<LSOption>http://myurl</LSOption>  
</Value>  
</Item>  
<Item>  
<Key>UserDisplayDimensions</Key>  
<Value>fullscreen</Value>  
</Item>  
</User_Blob></root>'" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "The specified node cannot be inserted as the valid child of th  
is node, because the specified node is the wrong type."
```

I also tried the same answers second solution:

```xml
$xmlObject = New-Object XML
$xmlObject.Load("C:temp\Sample 2.xml")
```

and I could not get to the third line as I got this error before:

```
MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s): "There is no Unicode byte order mark. Cannot switch to  
Unicode."
```

I followed other solutions on a few powershell blogs and even tried a few `xml` modules and I've had no success.

To be clear I am simply looking for a way to import something like the sample file below as either a hashtable or a `PSObject`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<results command="list0" result="1">
    <items display_path="C:\Temp" lister="0x20517e0" path="C:\Temp" tab="0x4e2522">
        <item id="20" name="White.png" path="C:\Temp\White.png" sel="0" type="0" />
        <item id="1" name="All Tasks.lnk" path="C:\Temp\All Tasks.lnk" sel="0" type="0" />
        <item id="15" name="Recipes.lnk" path="C:\Temp\Recipes.lnk" sel="1" type="0" />
        <item id="16" name="Dinner plan.lnk" path="C:\Temp\Dinner plan.lnk" sel="1" type="0" />
        <item id="14" name="Car.lnk" path="C:\Temp\Car.lnk" sel="1" type="0" />
        <item id="18" name="bike.lnk" path="C:\Temp\bike.lnk" sel="1" type="0" />
        <item id="5" name="blue.png" path="C:\Temp\blue.png" sel="0" type="0" />
        <item id="4" name="Black.png" path="C:\Temp\Black.png" sel="0" type="0" />
        <item id="7" name="File 2.ahk" path="C:\Temp\File 2.ahk" sel="0" type="0" />
        <item id="9" name="File 4.ahk" path="C:\Temp\File 4.ahk" sel="0" type="0" />
        <item id="6" name="file 1.ahk" path="C:\Temp\file 1.ahk" sel="0" type="0" />
        <item id="8" name="File 3.ahk" path="C:\Temp\File 3.ahk" sel="0" type="0" />
    </items>
</results>
```

PSVersion 7.3.0-preview.7

Windows Terminal Preview 1.15.2003.0

---

I have taken the liberty to cross post this question on other forums as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `[xml](Get-Content "C:temp\Sample 2.xml" -Raw)` should be all you need

Comment: When the XML has UTF-16 encoding, a BOM (byte order mark) is mandatory, because it could be either UTF-16 LE (typical for Windows) or UTF-16 BE, which can only be determined from the BOM. Try saving the XML file again using UTF-16 LE encoding (you can do so in the "save as" dialog of Windows Notepad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, when input directly into the PS console. When loading from a file you may have to account for unexpected encoding, BOM, extraneous characters, etc. Encodings and file formats are a whole chapter by themselves. All of us having encoding pain at some point :)

You probably know already but @"..."@ is a multi-line string literal in PS. Using PS's default string encoding, so it just works :)

```
$xmlString = @"
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<results command="list0" result="1">
    <items display_path="C:\Temp" lister="0x20517e0" path="C:\Temp" tab="0x4e2522">
        <item id="20" name="White.png" path="C:\Temp\White.png" sel="0" type="0" />
        <item id="1" name="All Tasks.lnk" path="C:\Temp\All Tasks.lnk" sel="0" type="0" />
        <item id="15" name="Recipes.lnk" path="C:\Temp\Recipes.lnk" sel="1" type="0" />
        <item id="16" name="Dinner plan.lnk" path="C:\Temp\Dinner plan.lnk" sel="1" type="0" />
        <item id="14" name="Car.lnk" path="C:\Temp\Car.lnk" sel="1" type="0" />
        <item id="18" name="bike.lnk" path="C:\Temp\bike.lnk" sel="1" type="0" />
        <item id="5" name="blue.png" path="C:\Temp\blue.png" sel="0" type="0" />
        <item id="4" name="Black.png" path="C:\Temp\Black.png" sel="0" type="0" />
        <item id="7" name="File 2.ahk" path="C:\Temp\File 2.ahk" sel="0" type="0" />
        <item id="9" name="File 4.ahk" path="C:\Temp\File 4.ahk" sel="0" type="0" />
        <item id="6" name="file 1.ahk" path="C:\Temp\file 1.ahk" sel="0" type="0" />
        <item id="8" name="File 3.ahk" path="C:\Temp\File 3.ahk" sel="0" type="0" />
    </items>
</results>
"@

$test = [xml]$xmlString
$test.results.items.item | where id -eq 16
# bit of xpath
$test.CreateNavigator().Select("//item[@id=16]").UnderlyingObject
```

Comment: This has to be sorcery, it just works...Thanks so much for this...as a side note I tried using `Select-Xml` and its `Xpath` perimeter on the `$test` variable  (`$test | Select-Xml -XPath "//results/items/item" | format-table`) but it just returns nothing. are you not doing the same thing when you invoked `$test.CreateNavigator().Select("//item[@id=16]").UnderlyingObject`?

Comment: @hellen_dorandt89 How about `$test | Select-Xml -XPath //results/items/item | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node | Format-Table`. Works for me in PS7.2.6